# Do we have any plugin available for wi-fi direct in phonegap?

Tags: cordova, wifi-direct

Do we have any plugin available for wi-fi direct in phonegap?

I want to share data using wi-fi and we can do that in native android using `wi-fi direct`, but when i checked for phonegap I didn't found any suitable doc's.

Is there a way I can do that in phonegap?

Any solutions or documents will be greatly helpful.

Thanks :)

Comment: yea.. looking for android

Comment: please, let me know if you find something ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm new at Cordova, but maybe you can use the function `cordova.exec`:

```
cordova.exec(function(winParam) {}, function(error) {}, "service",
         "action", ["firstArgument", "secondArgument", 42,
         false]);
```

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html

If it's only for android, ou might use these functions:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

Please let me know if you get anything!